# How to change `ggplot2` output to grey level?

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

I am looking for a smooth way to change a `ggplot2` output to grey level.

Here an example:

```
iris <- iris

library(mlr3)
example <- TaskClassif$new(id = "iris", backend = iris, target = "Species")

library(GGally, ggplot2, mlr3viz)
autoplot(example, type = "pairs")
```

[image: Output]

And what I wish to have is a scheme like this:

[image: What I would like to have]

To be honest, I am unable to solve my "problem" with `ggplot2`'s [cheatsheet](https://github.com/rstudio/cheatsheets/blob/master/data-visualization-2.1.pdf). I think I need sth. like `+ scale_color_grey(start = 0.8, end = 0.2)` or `+ scale_fill_grey(start = 0.8, end = 0.2)`.

Thanks!

Comment: Try to look http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-themes-and-background-colors-the-3-elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure where the confusion is coming from, as your intuition seems totally correct to me. When I use the `scale_colour_grey()` is does exactly what you would expect and what you describe should be the outcome.

```
autoplot(example, type = "pairs") +
  scale_colour_grey(aesthetics = c("fill", "colour")) + # fill and colour at the same scale
  theme_classic() # Eliminite confusing grey background
```

[image]

If you want the species/grey level order reversed, you can set limits in the scale, e.g.:

```
autoplot(example, type = "pairs") +
  scale_colour_grey(aesthetics = c("fill", "colour"),
                    limits = rev(unique(iris$Species))) +
  theme_classic()
```

Comment: That's fantastic, thank you! I overlooked to write it as `astheticts = c("fill", "colour")`. That's probably because I have no experience with `ggplot2`. Thank you!